# Move_base launch failed

Tags: navigation, move-base, eigen

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed totally the same with the tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup, but when I launch the move_base.launch, I get this error

:[FATAL] [1419514415.947186074]: Failed to create the base_local_planner/TrajectoryPlannerROS planner, are you sure it is properly registered and that the containing library is built? Exception: MultiLibraryClassLoader: Could not create object of class type base_local_planner::TrajectoryPlannerROS as no factory exists for it. Make sure that the library exists and was explicitly loaded through MultiLibraryClassLoader::loadLibrary()

This is the log:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/r7n7ycxepsmy5f5/Untitled.png?dl=0

Please help me.

---

I installed the navigation stack from source the problem above is solved. However, I get another error as below:

:move_base: /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h:69: Eigen::internal::plain_array<T, Size, MatrixOrArrayOptions, 16>::plain_array() [with T = float, int Size = 4, int MatrixOrArrayOptions = 0]: Assertion `(reinterpret_cast<size_t>(array) & 0xf) == 0 && "this assertion is explained here: " "http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/TopicUnalignedArrayAssert.html" " **** READ THIS WEB PAGE !!! ****"' failed.

I defined both EIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE and EIGEN_DISABLE_UNALIGNED_ARRAY_ASSERT in the move base file but the error is still occured.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200061/move_base-launch-failed/) by [heng](https://answers.ros.org/users/21237/heng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2014-12-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-12-25**:
Please post the actual logs otherwise people can't help.

**Comment by [heng](https://answers.ros.org/users/21237/heng/) on 2014-12-26**:
This is my first time post a question, I can't upload the photo so I just share the link of my log picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to make sure all of the navigation stack is installed properly.

If you installed from source, you need to include all the packages in the navigation stack/repository.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2014-12-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [heng](https://answers.ros.org/users/21237/heng/) on 2014-12-27**:
I installed the navigation stack by using sudo apt get instead from source, so I suppose it is installed properly? Or it is better to install from source?

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-12-27**:
apt-get is fine. Did you apt-get ros-***-base-local-planner? (where ***=your distro, i.e. hydro)

**Comment by [heng](https://answers.ros.org/users/21237/heng/) on 2014-12-27**:
I have updated my question. I installed it again from source and the problem solve. But another problem arises, I get an error as stated in the end part of my question. I found some answer from other question and I did the same, but it still doesn't work.